# MariaDB dead lock when updating row using primary key

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

Getting deadlock in MariaDB(10.1) when updating user's last activity in the table.

The query causing the error is

```
UPDATE auth_sessions SET last_activity_time='2018-12-21 05:45:39 WHERE id= 481;
```

We execute this query inside the procedure whenever users perform any action on the application.

Below is the status received from `show engine innodb status ;`

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-12-21 05:45:39 7fe5b8e6eb00
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3742528, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 12 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 81 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1941, OS thread handle 0x7fe5b5df4b00, query id 43106 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
UPDATE auth_sessions
                                                    SET last_activity_time= NAME_CONST('time_now',_latin1'2018-12-21 05:45:39' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci')
                                                    WHERE id= NAME_CONST('temp_session_id',481)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 470949 page no 6 n bits 160 index `PRIMARY` of table `xfusion_auth_engine`.`auth_sessions` trx table locks 5 total table locks 5  trx id 3742528 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3742527, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
12 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 81 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1943, OS thread handle 0x7fe5b8e6eb00, query id 43123 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
UPDATE auth_sessions
                                                    SET last_activity_time= NAME_CONST('time_now',_latin1'2018-12-21 05:45:39' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci')
                                                    WHERE id= NAME_CONST('temp_session_id',481)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 470949 page no 6 n bits 160 index `PRIMARY` of table `xfusion_auth_engine`.`auth_sessions` trx table locks 5 total table locks 5  trx id 3742527 lock mode S locks rec but not gap lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 470949 page no 6 n bits 160 index `PRIMARY` of table `xfusion_auth_engine`.`auth_sessions` trx table locks 5 total table locks 5  trx id 3742527 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
```

Table Schema - Auth Session

```
CREATE TABLE `auth_sessions` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Auto Increment ID',
    `user_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Email',
    `user_key` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Key',
    `application_key` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Application Key',
    `created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Session Creation Time',
    `expires` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Session Expiration Time',
    `is_logged_in` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tells whether user is logged in or not ',
    `session_key` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Session Key per user per application key',
    `last_activity_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last recorded time for any activity',
    `session_key_bin` BINARY(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Binary ID of Session Key',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `ix_session_key_bin` (`session_key_bin`)
)

COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB

;
```

Any clue or solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Show us the rest of the transaction, from `START TRANSACTION` to `COMMIT`.

Comment: I am not starting any transaction as auto-commit is set to 1.

Comment: Hmmm... That throws a monkey wrench in.  You have two connections hitting the same row at the same time?

Comment: Aha -- Tell me about `temp_session_id`.

Comment: And this seems strange:  "total table locks 5"

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE auth_sessions`.  It's a long shot, but it might give a clue.

Comment: `temp_session_id` is the variable declared in the procedure which contains the primary key id of row.

Comment: The query which is use to get the id is - `SET temp_session_id=(SELECT id from auth_sessions where session_key='some UUID' limit 1);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185593/discussion-between-abhishek-ginani-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a multi-statement transaction (which you don't):

Sometimes the cure for problems similar to this is to have

```
SELECT ... WHERE id= 481  FOR UPDATE;
```

before the `UPDATE`, but inside the transaction.

Not all deadlocks are preventable.  It is best to be prepared to handle deadlocks.  This particular one can probably be correctly handled by:

Plan A (preferred):  Replay the `UPDATE`.

Plan B (probably ok, considering the query's purpose):  Ignore the deadlock.

Plan C (I don't know if it will work; if it does, is should eliminate this kind of deadlock):

```
UPDATE auth_sessions
    SET   last_activity_time = NOW()
    WHERE last_activity_time != NOW()
      AND id = 481;
```

The idea is to avoid trying to update if the value is already set to the desired time.